# Home page won't load on local (MAMP) WP site. All other pages load fine (incl admin)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, timeout

I opened up a local WP project I hadn’t worked on for a couple weeks. It used to work just fine but without having changed anything, suddenly the (static) home page doesn’t open anymore in Google Chrome.

When I go to “localhost:8888” (the default URL for MAMP) the page seems like it’s loading for a while and then I receive the “This site can not be reached” time out error.

Oddly enough the URL redirects to “192.168.1.2:8888”. This doesn’t happen when I type in a specific page URL like “localhost:8888/products”. The page loads without any problems. Admin pages also work fine, as well as the MAMP welcome page and phpMyAdmin.

Also, when I go to Appearance -> Customize, it loads my home page just fine, supporting my theory that the redirect is causing the error, though I’m not quite sure why it’s happening.

When I open up Safari the home page loads completely, though it does take a few seconds. I’m not sure if that’s just Safari being slow or if it’s still being redirected and Safari just manages to handle it somehow.

Things I have tried:

- Checking the DB integrity using both WP Repair and phpMyAdmin, as
  well as checking all post/files/etc in the Admin Dashboard for
  possible corrupt data.
- Changing the ports in MAMP (and in the db).
- Defining WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME explicitly in wp-config. Checking the
  database for the values of WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME. Both are correctly
  set to http://localhost:8888. I also searched all database tables and
  project files for the IP 192.168.1.2, just in case I had done
  something stupid. Only the “wp_posts” table has that IP under the
  guid column, which I assume is irrelevant (the post pages load fine).
- Using my old modem (the only possible thing I remember changing).
- Removing all browser cache and cookies.
- Logging out of WP, rebooting, etc…i.e. the usual suspects.
- Disabling all plugins.
- Saving permalink settings again.

As you can imagine, it’s getting quite frustrating. Any advice at all is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: whats an issue please tell in brief

Comment: Try to some other page as homepage.

Comment: @vel Just tried it, same thing happens. :/

Comment: enable the error reporting and check

Comment: Error checking is enabled but no error log is created in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it finally. The fact that it worked fine on Safari made me think the fault lay completely with Chrome.

So I opened up Chrome dev tools and did a Hard Reload. Not sure how that differs from emptying cache/cookies but it worked!